# P5.js: How to know if a key is no longer pressed?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

How do I know if a key is released? This question has been answered for C# coders but I do not use C#.

```
function keyPressed() {
  if (keyIsDown(ENTER)){
      player.up();
  }
}

this.up = function() {
    if (this.y == 350){
        if (keyIsDown(ENTER)){
            this.velocity -= this.gravity*15;
        }
        else{
            this.velocity += this.gravity*20000;
        }
    }
}
```

This code does not seem to work. (Don't mind the integers I used.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a key is pressed the [`keyPressed`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyPressed) event is called one time.
When a key is released the [`keyReleased`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyReleased) event is called one time.
The variable [`keyCode`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyCode) tells you which key is pressed or released. 
The [`keyIsDown`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyIsDown) function can be used to check if a specific key is currently down, i.e. pressed.

Note that `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` are not called continuously when a key is held:

```js
function draw() {}

function keyPressed(){
    if (keyCode === ENTER){
      console.log("Enter key pressed");
    }
    return false; // prevent any default behavior
}

function keyReleased(){
    if (keyCode === ENTER){
      console.log("Enter key released");
    }
    return false; // prevent any default behavior
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to check and handle the state of a key continuously, then you can do this in the `draw` function, by checking for `keyIsDown`:

```
function draw() {

    .....

    if ( keyIsDown(ENTER) ) {
        this.velocity -= this.gravity*15;
    } else {
        this.velocity += this.gravity*20000;
    }

    .....

}
```

This simple example changes the color of the canvas if the ENTER key is held down (of course the focus has to be on the canvas):

```js
function draw() {
    if ( keyIsDown(ENTER) )
        background(255,0,0)
    else
        background(0,0,255)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -4):

you can use the following code:

```js
$(document).keyup(function(){
console.log('key up');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

remember to add jquery!

Comment: P5.js has its own event handling code, and you should not override it with JQuery.